# How to predict new datasets after the `tune_nested`?

Tags: mlr3

```
# retrieve task
task = tsk("pima")

# load learner and set search space
learner = lrn("classif.rpart", cp = to_tune(1e-04, 1e-1, logscale = TRUE))

# nested resampling
rr = tune_nested(
  method = "random_search",
  task =  task,
  learner = learner,
  inner_resampling = rsmp("holdout"),
  outer_resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  term_evals = 10,
  batch_size = 5
)
```

So if now I define a new dataset:

```
new_data = as.data.table(task)[1:10,]
```

How can I predict the result of the new_data?

Answer (score 4):

> Keep in mind that nested resampling is a statistical procedure to estimate the predictive performance of the model trained on the full dataset. Nested resampling is not a procedure to select optimal hyperparameters. The resampling produces many hyperparameter configurations which should be not used to construct a final model.

mlr3book section 4.3 "[nested resampling](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/optimization.html#nested-resampling)"

The gallery post "[Practical Tuning Series - Tune a Support Vector Machine](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/posts/2021-03-09-practical-tuning-series-tune-a-support-vector-machine/)" gives a practical example on how to build a model for prediction and for what nested resampling is used.